# Creating POST request to scrape website with python where no network form data changes

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, post, web-scraping

I am scraping a website that dynamically renders with javascript. The urls don't change when hitting the `>` button So I have been trying to look at the inspector in the network section and more specifically the "General" section for the "Request Url" and the "Request Method" as well as in the "Form Data" section looking for any sort of ID that could be unique to distinguish each successive page. However when recording a log of clicking the `>` button from page to page the "Form Data" data seems to be the same each time (See images):
[image]
[image]

Currently my code doesn't incorporate this method because I can't see it helping until I can find a unique identifier in the "Form Data" section. However, I can show my code if helpful. In essence it just pulls the first page of data over and over again in my while loop  even though I'm using a driver with selenium and using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xpath of > button").click()` before trying to get the data with BeautifulSoup.

(Updated code see comments)

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
masters_list = []


def extract_info(html_source):
    # html_source will be inner HTMl of table
    global lst
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
    lst = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')[0]
    masters_list.append(lst)

    # i am printing just id because it's id set as crypto name you have to do more scraping to get more info


chrome_driver_path = '/Users/Justin/Desktop/Python/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
url = 'https://cryptoli.st/lists/fixed-supply'
driver.get(url)
loop = True

while loop:  # loop for extrcting all 120 pages
    crypto_table = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'DataTables_Table_0').get_attribute(
        'innerHTML')  # this is for crypto data table

    extract_info(crypto_table)

    paginate = driver.find_element(
        By.ID, "DataTables_Table_0_paginate")  # all table pagination
    pages_list = paginate.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')
    # we clicking on next arrow sign at last not on 2,3,.. etc anchor link
    next_page_link = pages_list[-1].find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')

    # checking is there next page available
    if "disabled" in next_page_link.get_attribute('class'):
        loop = False

    pages_list[-1].click()  # if there next page available then click on it
df = pd.DataFrame(masters_list)
print(df)
df.to_csv("crypto_list.csv")
driver.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: may be when you are clicking button is not making any request that's why it's not changing in any value , button is showing hidden stuff in html , see the response of url in network

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Could you direct me to where I see the response of the URL in the network? Is it shown in the screenshot above? When I run the code it starts the browser and I can see it clicking from one page to the next until it runs out which causes the driver to quit. It just doesn't return anything but the first page over and over.

Comment: yes , it is shown in the screenshot above & you can share some code so it will be easy for others to solve .

Comment: Ok just updated the code. I don't understand where the "hidden stuff in html" is. Could you explain to me what they means?

Comment: actually hidden is wrong word to use , i mean stuff that hide through javascript or css . can i ask about url & the stuff you want to scrape

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the clarification! I am wanting to scrape the data table on each page. I am able to get page one but after that it just keeps printing page one again and again. Here is the url: https://cryptoli.st/lists/fixed-supply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using my own code to show how i am getting the table i add explanation as comment for important line

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract_info(html_source):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source,'html.parser') #html_source will be inner HTMl of table 
    lst = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
    for i in lst:
        print(i.get('id')) # i am printing just id because it's id set as crypto name you have to do more scraping to get more info



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://cryptoli.st/lists/fixed-supply'
driver.get(url)
loop = True

while loop: #loop for extrcting all 120 pages 
    crypto_table = driver.find_element(By.ID,'DataTables_Table_0').get_attribute('innerHTML') # this is for crypto data table 

    print(extract_info(crypto_table))

    paginate = driver.find_element(By.ID, "DataTables_Table_0_paginate") # all table pagination 
    pages_list  = paginate.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'li')
    next_page_link = pages_list[-1].find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'a') # we clicking on next arrow sign at last not on 2,3,.. etc anchor link

    if "disabled" in next_page_link.get_attribute('class'): # checking is there next page available 
        loop = False

    pages_list[-1].click() # if there next page available then click on it
```

so main answer of your question is when you click on button, selenium update the page then you can use `driver.page_source` to get updated html. some times (*not this url) page can have ajax request which can take some time so you have to  wait till the selenium load the full page.

Comment: Thank you! Just ran this and saw that it pulls all of the names but no other data from the table. So to take it a next step and get the rest of the info I need to grab the id of each of the other columns? Is there a way to plug all of that data back into a pandas dataframe and append all the tables together to be saved in one csv? I will try to figure out myself just want to make sure I'm on the right track. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I will suggest you to play with code and try if you get any error ask another question , stackoverflow always ready to help.

Comment: Ok I got all the data and was able to get it into a dataframe and csv file however I can't figure out the last bit of getting rid of the html and just getting the data I want for each column (see updated code in original post and the screenshot of output of name column above. Any ideas? Thanks, Justin

Comment: @JustinBenfit  you have to learn BeautifulSoup , see their docs is very easy to learn. Secondly in your code you are using `find_all('tr')` which is giving you each row of cryptocurrency but in each row in it 19 `td`  elements of html you have to find_all of them , then suppose you want to extract `Max Supply` then you have to exract 5 no. of `td` of each `tr` & if you want to extract text between html element use `get_text` function .

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I got it to work! I learned a ton in the process as well.